# Why am I getting *** _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x97480b0 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, static, autorelease

I have noted several other threads on this topic and have tried wrapping my threaded code with:
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
[pool release];

but the errors still come.

I am using a static method to instantiate a dictionary of words.
Here is some code:

```
    -(id)init
     [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadDictionary:) toTarget:[IntroScreen class] withObject:nil];
     [NSThread setThreadPriority:1.0];
     return self;
    }

    +(void)loadDictionary:(id)param
    {
     NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
     [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"click.wav"];
     [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"pop.wav"];
     [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"dink.wav"];
     [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:@"musicloop.wav"];
     [WordDictionary configDictionary];
     [pool release];
    }

+(void)configDictionary
{
 NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
 Serializer * mySerializer = [[Serializer alloc] init];

 [WordDictionary setDictionary:[mySerializer readApplicationPlist:@"x"]];
 NSString * string;
 NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] 
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"x.txt"];
 NSString *info = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
 NSArray *arrayOfLines = [info componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"];
 [WordDictionary setDictionary:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]];
 [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
 int len = [arrayOfLines count];
 for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
 {
  string = [arrayOfLines objectAtIndex:i];
  NSString * blankString = [NSString stringWithString:@""];
  [[WordDictionary dictionary] setObject:blankString forKey:string];
  double calc = ((double)i / (double)len) * 100.0;
  [WordDictionary setProgress:(int)calc];
 }

 [mySerializer writeApplicationPlist:[WordDictionary dictionary] toFile:@"s"]; 
 [WordDictionary setProgress:100];
 [pool release];
}
```

Is there something I should know about using static class methods with new selector threads?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

First, there are no static methods in Objective-C.  There are class methods.

Secondly, your code shows both methods wrapped in autorelease pools.  The warning must be coming from somewhere else.

Finally, your code leaks like a sieve. You aren't following the memory management rules.  And there are some nonsense statements in there.

Specifically:

```
[WordDictionary setDictionary:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]];
```

Unless `+setDictionary:` is breaking the memory management rules, the above leaks.

This statement `[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];` effectively does nothing unless you do something with the return value.

Also, `mySerializer` is leaking.

Try running the analyzer over your code and fixing the problem.  You should also read [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) and [this](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ah the `[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];` was part of an experiment I was attempting to make the dictionary access faster.  I should have removed it from this example.

I have just read the memory management rules, and understand that 
`[WordDictionary setDictionary:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]];` appears to be poorly planned instantiation because I have no way to release it from within `configDictionary` as the reference is lost.  But actually I don't ever want to release it, it lives for the entire lifetime of my application.  Probably bad practice just the same.

`mySerializer` should definitely be released at the bottom.

I was just wondering if class methods had any special rules regarding autorelease pools and memory.

I will look over the documents you sent me and try to figure out the Analyzer, thank you for your help.